# Unable to set width of UICollectionViewCell content with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

[image]

I'm creating a grid view using a collection view but some big iPhones have spacing on the right side.

I used the code below in collectionViewLayout method:

```
return CGSizeMake(cellSize / 4, cellSize /4)
```

Please see the image for more details.

Comment: Have you added constraints between your collectionView and the view edges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved after added below method:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {

    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    //Invalidate collection view layout to make it recalculate
    [yourCollectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cell size is not the issue. The problem is the **spacing**. It can't have **fixed item size** and **fixed item spacing** at the same time. So you have to make one of them dynamic.

Try calculate spacing or item size in flowLayout ;)

Comment: thanks, I can't set fixed item size. if I can increase cellSize then gridView display only three cell.